# How to achieve the following structure in javafx?

Tags: javafx-2

I have to create the architecture shown in the image below.
The inner components can be created very easily but in which container I would place them is the question. BorderPane, AnchorPane, GridPane.. These cannot contain JFXPanel as achild node.

Hence , the task is to convert the swing panel into jfxpanel. So each element should be of javafx.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JFXPanel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/embed/swing/JFXPanel.html) is for embedding JavaFX scenes inside a Swing application, which doesn't sound like what your are doing, so a JFXPanel is probably the wrong component type to use for your application.

I guess (and I could be wrong) that your application is a JavaFX application in which you would like to embed a Swing component - in which case you use a [SwingNode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/embed/swing/SwingNode.html).

```
JavaFX scene
 - JavaFX layout pane root
   - JavaFX ScrollPane 
     - SwingNode 
       - Swing component
```

In general, [mixing JavaFX and Swing is not usually recommended](https://dlemmermann.wordpress.com/2014/07/17/javafx-tip-9-do-not-mix-swing-javafx/).

I note that your question is tagged javafx-2, so note that SwingNode only exists from Java 8 on; i.e., it does not exist in Java 7, so there is no way to accomplish the structure you outline in your question within the context of Java 7 or JavaFX 2.2.